# What is the quickest way to make a widget?

Tags: widgets, customization

I have some PHP code that I would like to pull out of an existing page of a template, and put into a widget so I can move it around.

What is the quickest way to create a widget?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Developing_Widgets_on_2.8.2B) is the quickest way to make a widget that's reusable.  Example use:

```
class My_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    /** 
      * PHP4 constructor
      */
    function My_Widget() {
        My_Widget::__construct();
    }

    /**
      * PHP5 constructor
      */
    function __construct() {
        // actual widget processes
    }

    /** 
      * Echo the settings update form
      *
      * @param array $instance Current settings
      */
    function form($instance) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    /** 
      * Update a particular instance
      *
      * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via form()
      * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance
      * @return array Settings to save or bool (false) to cancel saving
      */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }

    /** 
      * Echo the widget content
      *
      * @param array $args Display arguments including before_title, after_title, before_widget, and after_widget
      * @param array $instance The settings for the particular instance of this widget
      */
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }
}
register_widget('My_Widget');
```

Comment: Please add the input and return types. Then it would be a good minimal reference. :)

Comment: "input and return types" for ... what?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't particularly care about having proper custom widget you can use a plugin like [PHP Code Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) to run your code snippet

Comment: This *is* a very fast method and is relatively easy to implement.  Just remember that it's not very portable (which might not matter to you anyway).

Comment: @EAMann portable meaning across blogs / installable?

Comment: *@Joseph* meaning across blogs, different sites, and different sidebars within the site.  If it's a standalone widget that you dropped in the `functions.php` file or in a plug-in, you can take it anywhere.  If it's drop-in code in a PHP Code Widget, you'll have to create a new PHP Code Widget each time and copy-paste the drop-in code.